# Android PDFDocument: disable including fonts into PDF file

Tags: android, fonts, pdfdocument

I creating small PDF files, but they are quite large (around 230kB) although there is only few words of text.

The large size of PDF is caused by included fonts.

My question is if there is way to somehow disable including fonts into PDF with native `PDFDocument` library.

I do not care what font is used, hope some generic will be good.

[image]

Comment: Well your PDF has to have a font and Roboto is Androids default font.

Comment: Did you solve this?